# Creating GUI and populating later the DefaultComboBoxModel of a JComboBox using SwingUtilities still freeze JFrame while populating thread is running

Tags: java, swing, invokelater, swingutilities

I try to create and show a GUI and to populate later a DefaultComboBoxModel using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

But the UI is still freezing and components are not displayed until the loading thread has completed.

The main frame is instantiated by Spring application context.Building/showing GUI through "fullInitialize" method called by Spring after frame initialization has completed (see method code below).

```
    <bean id="view" class="be.philippefery.bigmap.view.MainView" init-method="fullInitialize">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="applicationTitle" />
        <property name="i18n" ref="i18n" />
        <property name="progressListener" ref="progressBar" />
        <property name="jb_importGpx" ref="gpxImport" />
        <property name="jb_importPointsOfInterest" ref="poisImport" />
        <property name="jp_gpxList" ref="gpxFilteredTablePanel" />
        <property name="jp_poiList" ref="poiFilteredTablePanel" />
    </bean>
```

MainView class (MainView extends JFrame):

```
    private void fullInitialize() throws IOException {
        //Creating the UI here
        //This includes a JList and its model which should be populated later (see below)
        createAndShowGUI();             

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Time consuming task sending HTTP requests to check if a list of servers are available
                    //then filling a listModel instantiated through createAndShowGUI() method
                    initializeTilesServerList();                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```
    private void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException {
        this.initialize();
        this.jsonUtils = new JsonUtils();
        this.createComponents();
        this.buildLayout();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that, even when populating the list using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`, the UI isn't displayed until this thread is terminated.

This is what is displayed while `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` is running:
[while thread is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGeZX.png)

... and once terminated:
[once thread terminated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/505Ok.png)

Any idea?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of method `invokeLater`. Refer to [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: Thank your for you comment Abra but I don't see where the mistake is. Do you mean I should  use a SwingWorker instead?

Comment: *"I should use a SwingWorker instead"* That's what I'd have thought @Abra meant, yes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I give it a try...

Comment: This was the solution. It's working fine now using a SwingWorker. Thank you for your help Abra and @Andrew Thompson ;-)

Comment: *"Thank you for your help Abra"* And plus one for implementing the suggestion of @Abra without 99 back and forth comments and instead picking up the ball and running with it. I've seen too much of the opposite of that recently, and this was a refreshing change. Glad you got it sorted. :)